# How to sum 2 columns in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sum

I am trying to sum 2 columns in my grade-view, which contains `Debit` and  `RemaininAmount`, but it only gives me one result for one column. How can I sum for the second column?

This is my view :

```
    <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Debit)
        </td>

        <td>
            @{
var RemaininAmount = item.contracts.AmountOfRent - item.Debit;
            }

            @RemaininAmount
        </td>


</tbody> }
```

```
<td>Total</td>
<td>@Model.Sum(x => x.Debit)</td>
<td>@Model.Sum(s => s.RemaininAmount)</td>
```

This is my output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EjCI.png)

Comment: That looks to be working? Are you sure the problem here isn't your expectation?  Should you be using `@Model.Sum(s => s.contracts.AmountOfRent - s.Debit)` to match the value you're displaying in the cells? By which I mean: you're *summing* `s.RemaininAmount`, but that isn't the value that you're *displaying* anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're simply displaying different values in the data cells vs the total. You're displaying `item.contracts.AmountOfRent - item.Debit` but you are summing `s.RemaininAmount`. Maybe try:

```cs
@Model.Sum(s => s.contracts.AmountOfRent - s.Debit)
```

so that you sum the value you are displaying.